# Minimal value of probability according to the difference of a Levy-process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

Can we conclude for a Levy-Process, that for all $\epsilon>0$ it holds that 
$\min_{s\in [0,t]} \mathbb P\left(\left|X_t-X_s\right|\leq \epsilon\right)>0$?

Stochastic continuity doesn't seem to work, and the infinite divisibility property of $X_t$ may be useless since from the triangle inequality of $|\cdot|$ we get an estimate of the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the stationarity of the increments, this is equivalent to $$\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_s| \leq \epsilon)>0$$ for all $t>0$.

Without any additional assumptions this does, in general, not hold true. Consider for example $X_t := t$ (i.e. a deterministic drift process), then $$\mathbb{P}(|X_t| \leq \epsilon) = 0$$ for all $t>\epsilon$.

---

Additional question: Does there exist for any $t>0$ some $\epsilon>0$ such that

$$\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_s| \leq \epsilon)>0 \quad \dots ?$$

Yes, that's true. As already mentioned above, we have by the stationarity of the increments

$$\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_s| \leq \epsilon) = \min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_s| \leq \epsilon). \tag{1}$$

Since

$$\{|X_s| \leq \epsilon\} \supseteq \left\{\max_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s| \leq \epsilon \right\}$$

for all $s \in [0,t]$, we find

$$\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_s| \leq \epsilon) \geq \mathbb{P} \left( \max_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s| \leq \epsilon \right).$$

Since the Lévy process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has càdlàg sample paths, the random variable $Y:= \max_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s|$ is almost surely finite. By the montone convergence theorem (or the continuity of the measure $\mathbb{P}$),

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \max_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s| \leq \epsilon \right) \xrightarrow[]{\epsilon \to \infty} 1.$$

Consequently, we can choose $\epsilon>0$ (sufficiently large) such that

$$\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_s| \leq \epsilon) \geq \mathbb{P} \left( \max_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s| \leq \epsilon \right)>0.$$

Comment: thanks. May i ask you additional, if there is a plausible argumentation, that there exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\min_{s\in[0,t]}P(|X_t-X_s|\leq \epsilon) >0$ holds?

Comment: @ziT You mean whether for any fixed $t>0$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\min_{s \in [0,t]} \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_s| \leq \epsilon)>0$...? Or whether there exists some $t>0$ and some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\min_{s \in [0,t]} \dots >0$....?

Comment: the first case. For any fixed $t$ there exists some $\epsilon$ such that...

Comment: @ziT see my edited answer.

Comment: isn't there a typo? Shouldn't  $\epsilon$ go to infty in your scenario in the monotone convergence theorem? so we have $\max_{s\in[0,t]}|X_s|\leq \epsilon_{i}$, where $\epsilon_{i}$ is an increasing sequence to $\infty$. Otherwise i couldn't explain, why the probability tends to 1.

Comment: @ziT Yes, you are right.